# How can I find the valúes of T1 and T2, from the following table.

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem statment said:

> Let X and Y be two discrete random variables with joint distribution
>   given by the following table.
>
> ```
> We assume that  0.25<Theta<2.5 and 0<theta<0.35. Find Theta 1 and Theta 2 when   
> X and Y are independent.
> ```
>
> [image]

Theta i=Ti

i=1,2

---

I use first the condition of all values sum up to 1 and I have,

```
  1=4(T1)+6(T2).
```

**Question:** I don't know from where or how to obtain the second equation to have the valúes of T1 and T2.

Comment: What is _Theta_ and what is _theta_ ?

Comment: By independence the ratios $\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{\theta_1+2\theta_2}$  and $\frac{\theta_1+2\theta_2}{\theta_1+\theta_2}$ are the same. I don't understand the we assume stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independence implies that the marginal distribution of $Y$ does not depend on $X$. This is the condition:

$\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{\theta_1 + 2\theta_2}=\frac{\theta_1+2\theta_2}{\theta_1 + \theta_2}$

We also need the marginal distribution of $X$ to not depend on $Y$ but this provides the same condition. It simplifies to:

$\left(\theta_{1}+\theta_{2}\right)^2=\left(\theta_{1}+2\theta_{2}\right)^2$

This is true if and only if:

$\theta_{2}=0$

This leaves a uniform distribution, with $\theta_1$ in each cell.